# Remove or move the "there are more items in this folder on the server" message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-interface

I have my outlook inbox with most recent items on the bottom. This means that the "there are more items in this folder on the server" message always appears below my most recent e-mails, disturbing the layout of the inbox.

Is there any way to avoid this message from appearing or, better yet, move it to the top of the inbox?

Thanks in advance,

mortom

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Exchange account under cached exchange mode?

This is a normal behavior in Outlook 2016. It indicates that not all items are downloaded to your local data file (.ost). If you want to check more items, just click this link.

[image]

You can change the offline setting to “All” so that all items are downloaded to local data file. You will not see this link.
Currently, no option to move it to the top of the inbox.

Comment: It is indeed an Exchange account and I understand that the message has to appear. My remark is that for certain UI layouts (namely date ascending) it does not make much sense for it to appear at the bottom of the list.
But as you say it seems that it is currently impossible to change such behaviour.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: My understanding is that when finding an email, users will scroll down to search it. If they cannot see it even going to the bottom, they can click that link to search emails on the server.                                                                                                    If the link appears on the top, some users may unconsciously click on it without checking if the email has already been downloaded. That will increase the network traffic.